# SQL: Creating a view sorted by months and types [Complex]

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am trying to create a view based off an audit table in an Oracle PL-SQL database. The audit table stores the modification times of requests which can move through different status.
Either

**Opened -> Closed**

Or

**Opened -> Paused -> Resumed -> Closed**

The requests can also be of different types A, B or C Here is some sample data representing the table

| ID | Creation Time | Modification Time | Closure Time | Status | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | 01/01/2020 | null | Opened | A |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 04/01/2020 | null | Opened | B |
| 3 | 20/01/2020 | 20/01/2020 | null | Opened | C |
| 4 | 21/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 | null | Opened | A |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | 02/02/2020 | null | Paused | A |
| 3 | 20/01/2020 | 01/03/2020 | 01/03/2020 | Closed | C |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | 02/03/2020 | null | Resumed | A |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 05/04/2020 | null | Paused | B |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 01/05/2020 | null | Resumed | B |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | 05/06/2020 | 05/06/2020 | Closed | A |
| 2 | 04/01/2020 | 06/06/2020 | 06/06/2020 | Closed | B |
| 4 | 21/01/2020 | 08/06/2020 | 08/06/2020 | Closed | A |

I need to use this data to calculate metrics for the last day of every month:

**Total open requests:** Number of requests that are in any status other than 'Closed'

**Total paused requests:** Number of requests that are in status 'Paused'

**Work in progress:** Total open requests - Total paused requests

And all of these should be groups by Type. So the correct view for this data would be:

| Last day | Type | Total open requests | Total paused requests | Work in progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2020 | A | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 31/01/2020 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 31/01/2020 | C | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 28/02/2020 | A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 28/02/2020 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 28/02/2020 | C | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 31/03/2020 | A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 31/03/2020 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 30/04/2020 | A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 30/04/2020 | B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 30/04/2020 | A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 30/04/2020 | B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 31/05/2020 | A | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 31/05/2020 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |

To clarify things further lets consider the following situation:
| ID | Creation Time | Modification Time | Closure Time | Status | Type |
|----|---------------|-------------------|--------------|--------|------|
| 1  | 01/01/2020    | 01/01/2020        | null         | Opened | A    |
| 1  | 01/01/2020    | 04/04/2020        | null         | Paused | A    |

Request 1 should not be counted as Open for just 31/01/2020 but for 31/01/2020, 28/02/2020 and 31/03/2020. This is because it remains in the status up until it is changed on 04/04/2020 at which point the audit table records this change.

In a similar fashion, if the above 2 rows were the only rows in the audit table, then the view created should have an entry for every month between the 31/01/2020 until the last day of the month prior to todays date, showing 1 paused request in every month bar the first three:

| Last day | Type | Total open requests | Total paused requests | Work in progress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2020 | A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 28/02/2020 | A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 31/03/2020 | A | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 30/04/2020 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 31/05/2021 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have made functions which generate these values however they will have to be modified in order to separate by Type and I also don't feel its the most efficient way of doing this. Also worth noting is that is a request never reaches the 'Closed' stage, it should be shown as open for all months since its creation until the current month. Any and all help if very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: tag your dbms as well.

Comment: Are you looking for the state of requests at the end of the month? That is to say, if a request was in 2 states on the final day, would you count it twice or whichever the final state was?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if I follow your question, a request can only be in one state at each time. I have added another example which hopefully clarifies things further - either way, I appreciate you taking the time to look at my question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I assumed your table name as testing:

```
select * from 
    (select distinct x.last_day, x.type,
        ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (select distinct type, id from testing t2 WHERE STATUS <> 'Closed' and t2.creation_time <= x.last_day and t2.type = x.type)) - (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (select distinct type, id from testing t2 WHERE STATUS = 'Closed' and t2.closure_time <= x.last_day and t2.type = x.type))) open_request,
        ((SELECT count(1) FROM (select distinct type, id from testing t2 WHERE STATUS = 'Paused' and t2.creation_time <= x.last_day and t2.modification_time <= x.last_day and t2.type = x.type)) - (SELECT count(1) FROM (select distinct type, id from testing t2 WHERE STATUS = 'Resumed' and t2.creation_time <= x.last_day and t2.modification_time <= x.last_day and t2.type = x.type))) paused_request
    from (select distinct lastdaytable.LASTDAY AS LAST_DAY, t.TYPE, t.id
          from testing t, 
               (SELECT mo, lastday
                FROM (SELECT mod(ROWNUM -1, 12)+1 AS mo,
                             last_day(TO_DATE((EXTRACT(DAY FROM (select min(creation_time) from testing))|| '/'|| (mod(ROWNUM -1, 12)+1)|| '/'|| (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (select min(creation_time) from testing)) + trunc(rownum/12))), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) lastday
                      FROM dual
                      CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ABS(TRUNC(months_between((select min(creation_time) from testing), SYSDATE))) + 1)
                WHERE mo <= rownum) lastdaytable
    ) x
)
where (open_request > 0 or paused_request > 0)
order by last_day asc, type asc;
```

Comment: Hey, really appreciate you taking the time to do this. I'll test this as soon as I can!